# Using the Position value of a recyclerview item to start another fragment

Tags: android

I have a recycler view with different articles. I can get the position of this recyclerview item , but I still don't know how to use that position to open the article in a full page/ another activity.

Here is how I manage to get the position:

```
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerview, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
}));
```

What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on any article they are redirected to a new fragment or activity where they can view the recycler in full..Regards

Comment: So what is your problem? Just redirect it inside onItemClick() method.

Comment: are you using a cursor or and array for the adapter?

Comment: am using  an array @ShriyanshGautam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this start a new activity using Intent and pass Position as parameter with intent than in your detail activity fetch result based on that position

```
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerview, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {                @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {                 

             Intent i = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("email",list.get(position).getEmail());
             i.putExtra("address",list.get(position).getAddress());
             i.putExtra("image",list.get(position).getImageurl());
             startActivity(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
        }));
```

Comment: how do i access this i.putExtra("POSITION",position); as a varibale to perform my search with?

Comment: can you explain in brief @user8532743

Comment: is this correct Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("desiredData")

Comment: I think this comment is regarding to my answer

Comment: @user8532743 `Intent receivedIntent = getIntent(); String data = intent.getStringExtra("desiredData")` to recieve data in detail activity

Comment: @NileshRathod is it possible to get the item onclicked data and pass it over to the next activity? i.e i have articles with text and image, can i pass them to the  next activity or do i have to perfom a new query

Comment: @user8532743 yes you can pass  it over to the next activity

Comment: @NileshRathod please demonstrate with one field: this is how i populate: listdata.setEmail(email);
                    listdata.setAddress(address);
                    listdata.setImageurl(image);
                    list.add(listdata);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using array as input to the adapter for data then you can access the data at the position inside onItemClick and onItemLongClick

```
String yourArray[];
//putting your data
youArray = new String[]{"Item1","Item2","Item3"};

recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerview, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     String yourDesiredData = youArray[position]; 
     //now you can fire intent with that data or start fragment transaction passing the data 
     if(yourDesiredData!=null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);

         intent.putExtra("desiredData",yourDesiredData);

         startActivity(intent);
     }


    //Or if you want Fragment then
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
     Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
     arguments.putString( "desiredData" , desired_string);
     fragment.setArguments(arguments);
     final FragmentTransaction ft = 
                 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment , FRAGMENT_TAG);
     ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(Navigation.this, "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String yourDesiredData = youArray[position]; 
    //now you can fire intent with that data or start fragment transaction passing the data 
     Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("desiredData",yourDesiredData);
        startActivity(intent);
  }
}));
```

You can retrieve the data in activity(in case of intent)

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("desiredData")
```

Or if using fragment you can retrieve the data like this

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
String data = arguments.getString("desiredData");
```

Comment: Thanks for the expertise Mr @ ShriyanshGautam

Comment: hey the position is not passed to the next activity. it says null

Comment: can you show me the code for your list activity and detail activity? Is the data that is put into the intent is not null?

Comment: on my list activity the toast displays the position name but when  the data is passed on to the next activity it says null when i try the same toast.

Comment: can you check that data is not null before putting it in intent
String yourDesiredData = youArray[position];

Comment: hey but the value format is an integer.? i think that is the problem here, it is an integer

Comment: have you modified it for putting the int value in the intent?